# Assigning a byte value to a char array

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion

The method Array.SetValue(Object value, int index) allows assignments involving value/array type pairs that would normally be allowed using the common indexer syntax, and throws an exception when you try to combine types that would normally not be allowed. For instance, consider the following local variable declaration:

```
int[] twoints = new int[2] { 5, 6 };
```

The following four lines do not throw any run-time or compile-time exceptions:

```
twoints[1] = (sbyte)7;
twoints.SetValue((sbyte)7, 1);
twoints[1] = (char)7;
twoints.SetValue((char)7, 1);
```

On the other hand, each of these four lines would throw an exception, either at run-time or at design-time:

```
twoints[1] = 4.5;
twoints.SetValue(4.5, 1);
twoints[1] = 4L;
twoints.SetValue(4L, 1);
```

However, when I assign a byte value to a char array I get strange results. The indexer syntax is refused at compile-time, and the API call of SetValue succeeds at run-time:

```
char[] twochars = new char[2] { 'A', 'B' };
twochars[1] = (byte)70;                 // Not OK, refused by the compiler
twochars.SetValue((byte)70, 1);         // OK, no exception at run-time
```

Why is this operation permitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `Array.SetValue()` follows the CLR rules, but the assignment follows the C# rules for type safety.

For the most part, local variables and temporaries of small integer types actually use `native int` in CIL.  The "type" is an illusion created and enforced by the C# compiler.

In the assignment, you have a `native int` on the IL operand stack, and the C# compiler performing type checking based on the type `System.Byte` and the C# rules for implicit conversion of integral types.  The CLR is perfectly happy to write the value into the array... the error message is added by the C# compiler.  And it probably should be a warning, but the C# language designers chose to specify that it would be an error.

In `Array.SetValue`, you have an actual boxed value of type `System.Byte`, and a conversion performed by the method you're calling (probably by delegation to some other function).